# The product of matrices is non-degenerate

Tags: linear-algebra

1) Matrices A and B have linearly independent rows.
Then correct statement is

a) $AA^T$ is nondegenerate

b) $B^TB$ is nondegenerate

c) $A^TB$ is nondegenerate

d) $AB^T$ is nondegenerate

e) a-d are incorrect

2) Matrices A and B have linearly independent columns.

a) $AA^T$ is nondegenerate

b) $B^TB$ is nondegenerate

c) $A^TB$ is nondegenerate

d) $AB^T$ is nondegenerate

e) a-d are incorrect

Thank you

Comment: Please tell us what exactly your definition of a "degenerate matrix" is in this context.  It sounds by "degenerate" you mean "non-singular" or "invertible", but this usage is not standard and therefore needs to be clarified.

Comment: invertible (also nonsingular or nondegenerate)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to 1 is a, the answer to 2 is b, and the remaining statements are indeed false.  The following fact is worth knowing:

> Given a matrix $A$, the matrix $A^TA$ is non-degenerate if and only if the columns of $A$ are independent.  Similarly, the matrix $AA^T$ is non-degenerate if and only if the rows of $A$ are independent.

You should either check your notes for this fact or try to prove it on your own.  If you're interested in building counterexamples to the false statements, I recommend that you consider matrices that have either one row or one column.